# How to exclude files within my project from our release build?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, privacy

We have a project where we parse users calendars for important phone numbers and access codes. To test our parser we have real user calendars inside our test folder to parse and compare with an array of hard-coded correct results.

For legal and privacy reasons these calendar files cannot be included in our final release. How do I stop the calendar files being released in our release build?

Comment: Use two schemes? What's the related with Git?

Comment: It's related to git, because when in some time one of the developers decides to make the project public, all the former commits with all sensible user data will be available to you and me.

Comment: Create a folder, add your sample calendar files in it. Drag and drop and add it your project. Before releasing delete folder reference from Xcode project. I don't get it, why was this so confusing?

Comment: @SamB It's an Agile project we're going to release this multiple times over the course of the project. If we manually removed it each time we could easily forget and would have to rely on future teams who work on this code to do the same.

Comment: @Deco I have worked with many large software deployments and almost every company has a "build" document that they follow. Like step by step instructions a person follows to package a release so that none of the steps are missed. You don't really do large software team packaging by memory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Several things to consider:

- Replace real private data. Really. There is absolutely no reason
  to have personal data within your sources, repositories or binaries.
  Ever. You don't know who will work on the code in the future, or
  where your code will be, or what the user will think about it later.
- Testing parsing seems to be more appropriate in a unit test, which
  has its own target, so the (mock) data won't be in the binary of the
  app.
- Build a system to import data into your app. That might be
  convenient anyway.

You can select which files go into which target by selecting the "Target Membership" in Xcode's "Utility" area on the right. Just select the file in question and select the appropriate targets regarding the test.

Comment: it is currently a unit test. Does this mean it won't appear in the binary?

Comment: Replacing the data would be extremely time consuming and wouldn't be a realistic test, we've hundreds of calendar entries and I'd like to expand it to thousands, hardcoding the correct results in to an array by hand is already making the test quite cumbersome. Importing the data in to the app could work but we've no back end and would like to keep it this way. I couldn't think of any consistent way to access it other than in the testing folder alongside our tests.

Comment: I think we should remove the data but I can't see how to do it other than abandoning the test or keeping it local to one machine. It would also affect our unit test coverage.

Comment: For each file you can select in what targets it gets included - make your test data only available in your app, but not the unit tests.

Comment: how do I do this? This is pretty much what I'm looking to accomplish.

Comment: Select your file in the project navigator, and on the right side ("Utilities" area) you can select the "Target Membership". - Just like any source code file. :)

Comment: Can you put that as your answer for anyone else with this problem? If I phrased it badly I can edit the question.

Comment: @Deco Added a note at the end of the answer with the short description.